# detect controller type in module ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I created a module, basically what I want to do is,

in this module, there is a function that will work like before_filter. This function will perform the logic and determine what it should perform. Example

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  include Mymodule
  authorize_resources

  def create
  end

  def update
  end

end

module Mymodule
  def authorize_resources
     current_controller = params[:controller]
     if current_controller == 'jobs'
      //some logic
     end
  end
end
```

so how I actually can automatically detect the controller name based on where my function located such as jobs, users, and etc. This is something similar to CanCan, but I would like to make my own.

Besides, how can I raise an exception or redirect_to a path if it failed, is that need to extend some rails classes?

```
def authorize_resources
  if current_controller.class == 'jobs'
    //logic
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `if` to:

```
if(current_controller == JobsController)
```

If `params[:controller]` is the class itself, and

```
if(current_controller.class == JobsController)
```

If the variable is an instance of `JobsController`.

Comment: but, i would like to make it dynamically detect?  when the authorize_resources is invoke in a specific controller, it will detect what's the current_controller is ,and perform the logic. er..Mayb i updated, see whether is that what you meant..cz I'm not so understand about your answer.

Comment: @Nich: I get it! Give me a few minutes.

Comment: wouldn't you need to call authorize_resources in a before_filter?

Comment: erm, is that, my authorize_resources will call before_filter based on different logic, like I parse yaml data,and get ':index,:create' so, my before_filter will be that

Comment: Sorry @Nich for the delay. I'm not a rails guy, and it'll take me a moment to figure this out.

Comment: @Linuxios alright @_@ really thanks..u can contact me secret@live.com.my as well